Делегат и интерфейс - это отделение формы от содержания, а анонимные классы и функции - это отделение содержания от формы?
У меня вертится мысль, что делегат и интерфейс - это сущности родственные.
Это как бы форма, отделенная от содержания.
Интерфейс - это форма класса.
Делегат - это форма функции.
(На другом конце анонимные классы и функции - содержание, максимально отделенное от формы)
И там и там это позволяет нам создавать ссылки не на конкретные объекты, а на их форму. "Всё, что подходит по форме - подходит" - это позволяет перейти на новый уровень абстракции, "размышляя" о программе.
То есть по сути появление И. и Д. - это показатель развития "программистского мышления"
Было бы интересно почитать что думаете на этот счет.
